# How to round corners top left + top right corners for iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to round the top and left corners but know how to do it for iOS 11+ (cause of the easiest new feature) but can't do that for iOS 9-, could be cool if u guys could help me with that :)

Here's an image of how it looks like now without rounding -

[image]
for example for iOS 11+, I do it like this -

```
layer.maskedCorners = [
  .layerMinXMaxYCorner,
  .layerMaxXMaxYCorner
]
layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
```

Comment: How did you do it for iOS11+? You should be able to use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624368-init to add a corner radius only on top left, top right and then apply the mask.

Comment: @Larme for iOS 11+ i do it like this - 
    layer.maskedCorners = [
      .layerMinXMaxYCorner,
      .layerMaxXMaxYCorner
    ]
    layer.cornerCurve = .continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a UIView extension and add the below method in it:

```
extension UIView {
    
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.frame = self.bounds
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            self.layer.mask = mask
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can round corner radius of any views from any sides.
Example:

```
anyView.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 20)
```

**Note: Don't forget to set the clipsToBounds property of the view to true before using this method. Happy Coding :)**

Comment: unfortunately its the same :\ the corners are not rounded :\

Comment: I have used the same and it's working for me. Have you clipped bounds of your view @AviavSabag?

Comment: I didnt set the clipsToBounds to true :D my bad, thank you very much! and stay safe <3

Answer (score 1):

Write this method and put it wherever you need, for example in viewDidLoad:

```
private let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
private func setMaskLayers() {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        yourView.clipsToBounds = true
        yourView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    } else {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: yourView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    yourView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    } 
}
```

Comment: check now, I edited it a little bit. yourView has to be replaced with your view object

Comment: Ye I did it aswell :\ idk why it doesnt work, im applying it into layoutsubviews

Comment: Edit your question and show your code where you're calling your iOS11+ working code.